# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Microsoft Graph Access Token lost when application is restarted

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-web

Using `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and `Microsoft Graph API`, when the application is restarted the `Access Token` is lost. The user is still logged in, but is unable to perform any `Graph API` calls.

I have tried the recommendations mentioned here [Managing incremental consent and conditional access](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access) but was unable to refresh the token, and resume automatically.

Here is my Controller:

```
 readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
 private GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;
    
 public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
 {
     this.graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;          
     this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
 }


[HttpGet]
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] {"user.read"})]
public async Task<IActionResult> A()
{
    User user;
    try
    {
        var scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
        var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
        user = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    }
    catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
    {
        // token is invalid....
        // the throw causes a redirect to the User Login Page            
        throw ex.MsalUiRequiredException;
    }
    
    user = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    Serilog.Log.Debug("{@User}", user);
        
    return View();
}
```

In the code above, when the application is restarted the access token is
lost, and re-throwing the exception causes a redirect to the Login-Page.

If I then click the `Sign-in with Microsoft` button, the user is already signed-in,
there is no need to enter the credentials. If I then access the controller calling the `Graph API`, the API calls succeed.

How can I refresh the tokens before calling the API?

**Also how can I debug this?** If I set a breakpoint at `throw ex.MsalUiRequiredException;` It is of no use, I cannot see,
where the redirect get's it's value from.

Comment: You'll need to configure the token cache on Microsoft.Identity.Web to use a distributed cache instead of the default in-memory cache.

Comment: I am suspecting some {LoginPath} that I set in Startup is overriding the default behaviour, and is hard to debug. How does one use the debugger to when the redirect occurs....

Answer (score 0):

The Annotation `[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] {"user.read"})]`
Is responsible for dealing with the redirect.

For debugging, use the `AuthorizeForScopes` source file.

In this specific case the `AuthenticationScheme` was not set to a value,
and was null.

Annotate the Action method to enforce a specific Scheme.
e.g. `AuthenticationScheme=OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`

```
  [HttpGet]
  [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] {"user.read"}, AuthenticationScheme=OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
  public async Task<IActionResult> A()
  {
       // snipped
  }
```

This resulted into the desired redirect path:

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7B%7D)